# Ajax duplicating request after second call

Tags: jquery, ajax, duplicate-data

I have an HTML page and links. So each links call a new page inside div (#start_buttons_container).

Here is my jquery ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var loading = "<img src='css/images/loading.gif'/>";


    $('.start_buttons').click(function(){
        alert('request');
        var hrefname = $(this).attr('href').split(' ');
        var urlname = "parts/"+hrefname;
        $.ajax({

            url: urlname,
            cache: false,

            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#start_buttons_container').html(loading);
            },

            success: function(data){
              $("#start_buttons_container").html(data);
              $("#start_buttons_container").show(200);

            }

        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I am using this code and works good for me. But when I click the link on second time, alert happens 2 time, if I click 3rd time, alert happens 3 time.

**My question:**
How can I stop duplicating request if user will click the link 20 times?

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="form">

    <table border="0" align=center cellspacing="15" cellpadding="5">
        <tr class="tr1">

                <td align="left"><a class="button1 start_buttons" href="new-project.php">New Project</a></td>
                <td align="left"><a class="button1 start_buttons" href="user_projects.php">Import</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="start_buttons_container">
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:**

As I descripe after multiple clicking to buttons Ajax starts to respond later and site begins work hardly.
But I found one thing. If i will not use js external url (js/main.js) and will write the js code at below HTML codes Ajax works perfect and responds will be fast even if you will click 100 times. Why?

Comment: on each click alert will come but only one time/click, isn't it?

Comment: on each click alert is duplicated...

Comment: You shouldn't use `Caps Lock` when writing questions. There's a written rule that sentences written in capitals could be assessed as shouting by the reader.

Comment: There is nothing specific in this code that can cause such a behaviour. I believe the problem is somewhere else. Could you plz create a working fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong with this code, could you please show use the HTML markup as well?

Comment: I updated it for you and added note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including main.js in your AJAX HTML file that you're loading. When you reload or clear the HTML from the DOM, it still keeps the script. Move the script out so it's not part of the HTML that's being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Fix duplicate request ajax when click

```
$('.start_buttons').unbind().bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //.....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to prevent multiple simultaneous ajax requests. Try this:

```
$(function(){

    var loading = "<img src='css/images/loading.gif'/>",
        pending;


    $('.start_buttons').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //instead of return false
        if(pending) { //there is an ajax request running
           return; //do nothing
        }
        alert('request');
        var hrefname = $(this).attr('href').split(' ');
        var urlname = "parts/"+hrefname;
        pending = true; //mark as running            

        $.ajax({

            url: urlname,
            cache: false,

            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#start_buttons_container').html(loading);
            },

            success: function(data){
              $("#start_buttons_container").html(data);
              $("#start_buttons_container").show(200);
              pending = false; //mark as not running
            }

        });
    });
});
```

If you want to abort the one that is already running try this.

```
$(function(){

    var loading = "<img src='css/images/loading.gif'/>",
        pending;


    $('.start_buttons').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //instead of return false
        if(pending) { //there is an ajax request running
           pending.abort();
           return; //do nothing
        }
        alert('request');
        var hrefname = $(this).attr('href').split(' ');
        var urlname = "parts/"+hrefname;            

        pending = $.ajax({

            url: urlname,
            cache: false,

            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#start_buttons_container').html(loading);
            },

            success: function(data){
              $("#start_buttons_container").html(data);
              $("#start_buttons_container").show(200);
              pending = undefined; //clear current request
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No, did not help. If you read the note at below, I have written that, ajax responds fast if I will not use external js. But if I use external js link (js/main.js) ajax does not work fastly after clicking 3-4 time and responds later. Because it starts to duplicate. I will tray to send you the videolink and you will understand my question right.

Comment: Now it sounds like a complete nonsense, seriously. :) The first solution simply wont allow user to make another request before the previous one is done. One can click the link to death... :)

Comment: ммм, я нашел проблему. Оказывается был конфликт со скриптами jquery UI. Я удалил строку `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` и работает отлично. Спасибо за помошь!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkvve/8/) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;
    var loading = "<img src='css/images/loading.gif'/>";


    $('.start_buttons').click(function(){
        count++;
        if (count > 19) {
        return;
        }
        alert('request'+count);
        var hrefname = $(this).attr('href').split(' ');
        var urlname = "parts/"+hrefname;
        $.ajax({

            url: urlname,
            cache: false,

            beforeSend: function() {
            $('#start_buttons_container').html(loading);
            },

            success: function(data){
              $("#start_buttons_container").html(data);
              $("#start_buttons_container").show(200);

            }

        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for code. I had written the number 20 approximately =) My suppose is to do ajax request only 1 time.

Comment: I used count> 1.  in this case if you will click the next link with class, `start_buttons` it will not work. We need to find another solution to do ajax request only 1 time.

Comment: @RiKo, I got your point now. I think you may need to use id instead of class. Then you can make a matching. Or take id dynamically, create an array, check whether the id is available in it if yes then `return;` else   add it in to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple, you put action of appending/alert in loaded file. Action in base file get something from cache. So in loaded file, it would react unique every time.